# Commonly provided code to drop table does not work for me

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write a fail safe script that can be run on multiple platforms, part of which is dropping a table if it exists so that it can be re-created. Unfortunately, the commonly given execute immediate instruction gives an error.

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || user_platform;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

Note, if the table exists, it does not drop the table but gives me

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 39:
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'USER_PLATFORM' not allowed in this context
ORA-06550: line 2, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

If the table does not exist, I get a different error.

As an aside, can I specify a schema name for good measure on the drop?

Comment: Can you provide more code please? How are you populating your user_platform?

Comment: `user_platform` is a variable, which you haven't declared or populated. Is that actually supposed to be the table name - i.e. `'DROP TABLE user_platform'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are concatenating it, `user_platform` is a variable. If the table does not exist then you get:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'USER_PLATFORM' must be declared
```

which seems reasonable. If it does exist you get:

```
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'USER_PLATFORM' not allowed in this context
```

as you reported, which looks a bit stranger. In this case it can see there is no variable and tries other identifier types; it now finds the table as a possible identifier - but that isn't a valid object type for this context, hence that error.

You either need to just include the table name in the statement directly:

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE user_platform';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/
```

which works with our without the table existing, as you expect, with both just reporting:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or you could declare and populate a variable and use that:

```
DECLARE
  l_table_name user_tables.table_name%TYPE := 'user_platform';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || l_table_name;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/
```

There isn't much benefit in doing that here, but it might be useful if this becomes a procedure that you pass the table name into.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c6b3b58f00e09a071c4e737c2c1b02e8)